# Python: Calling functions whose names are stored in variables

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am developing an application with check the status of a bunch of sensors.

The way to get their status is very straightforward:

```
sensor_name.get_status()
```

Instead of writing several calls to check all those sensors, I was wondering if I could store all sensor names in a list of strings and let a `for` do the work for me.

Pretty much like this:

```
sensors_list = ['sensor_name_1', 'sensor_name_2', 'sensor_name_3']
for sensor in sensors_list:
    #call it :-)
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about, instead of keeping the names in the list, you just keep the sensors themselves in the list?

```
sensors = [sensor_1, sensor_2, sensor3]
for sensor in sensors:
    sensor.get_status()
```

Comment: You can't always control what format the list comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Use `locals` (I will set `sensor_name_1` to the `min` function just so it is callable):

```
>>> sensor_name_1 = min  # just an example function
>>> locals()['sensor_name_1']([1,2,3])
1
```

For your specific example, you would do:

```
sensors_list = ['sensor_name_1', 'sensor_name_2', 'sensor_name_3']
for sensor in sensors
    locals()[sensor].get_status()
```